# Correcting the error: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Here's my code:

np.random.seed(0)

luck_A = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (2, 1, 100))

A = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (2, 1, 100))

index_select_A = (np.argpartition(A, -10)[:, :, -10:])

result = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: luck_A[x, :, index_select_A[x]], axis=2, arr=luck_A)

I want to create an array which contains the elements of luck_A but only elements which indexes are in index_select_A. But when I run the code it keeps giving me the error: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type. But the elements in index_select_A are integers

I've already tried .astype(int). It didn't work

Comment: Rewrite the lambda as a function, and print `x`.  What is `apply` passing to your function? I think you'll see 1d selections from `luck_A`.  `apply` is a tricky function to use right.  A simple list comprehension will be simpler to use, and just as fast.  And since you are just doing indexing you probably don't even need that.

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
Cell In[3], line 9, in <lambda>(x)
      5 A = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (2, 1, 100))
      7 index_select_A = (np.argpartition(A, -10)[:, :, -10:])
----> 9 result = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: luck_A[x, :, index_select_A[x]], axis=2, arr=luck_A)

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

`index_select_A[x]` is highlighted.

Rewriting the lambda to allows some prints:

```
In [4]: def foo(x):
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:     print(index_select_A[x])
   ...:     return luck_A[x, :, index_select_A[x]]
   ...:     

In [5]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, axis=2, arr =luck_A)
[0.5488135  0.71518937 0.60276338 0.54488318 0.4236548  0.64589411
 0.43758721 0.891773   0.96366276 0.38344152 0.79172504 0.52889492
 0.56804456 0.92559664 0.07103606 0.0871293  0.0202184  0.83261985
```

...]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 np.apply_along_axis(foo, axis=2, arr =luck_A)

```
File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in apply_along_axis(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py:379, in apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)
    375 except StopIteration as e:
    376     raise ValueError(
    377         'Cannot apply_along_axis when any iteration dimensions are 0'
    378     ) from None
--> 379 res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
    381 # build a buffer for storing evaluations of func1d.
    382 # remove the requested axis, and add the new ones on the end.
    383 # laid out so that each write is contiguous.
    384 # for a tuple index inds, buff[inds] = func1d(inarr_view[inds])
    385 buff = zeros(inarr_view.shape[:-1] + res.shape, res.dtype)

Cell In[4], line 3, in foo(x)
      1 def foo(x):
      2     print(x)
----> 3     print(index_select_A[x])
      4     return luck_A[x, :, index_select_A[x]]

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

`apply` passes one row, shape (100,) of `luck_A` to the function (as `x`).  That's an array of floats.  Of course it can't be used as an index!

```
In [6]: luck_A.shape
Out[6]: (2, 1, 100)
```